# VMware Fusion 7.1.1 Windows 10 SVGA Workaround

Tags: wpf, windows, windows-10, vmware-fusion

While playing Windows 10 Preview in VMware Fusion 7.1.1 with opened accelerate 3D setting in Mac, windows built with WPF looks weird. I think it is stems from VMware Tools Graphic Driver (VMware SVGA). Do you know a workaround ?

Answer (score 0):

1. From VM Uninstall VMware tools
2. Shutdown VM
3. Change VM settings to
       Windows 10
4. Restart VM Windows
5. Delete all files in
       c:\windows\softwaredistribution\download
6. Run wuauclt.exe /updatenow
       from CMD as Administrator
7. Go to Windows Update and Windows 10
       started to download.